# Using the same button in different scenes?

Tags: java, javafx

I made a button,
    Button goBack= new Button("Voltar Atrás");

I called the button twice, the first time was in a HBox in scene 2, the second time was in a VBox within scene 3. Somehow it only appears in scene 3.

[image]

```
Label information=new Label("O Porto Jazz Fest é o maior evento do seu tipo no pais!");
information.getStyleClass().add("information");

Button goBack=new Button("Voltar atrás");
goBack.setOnAction(e->window.setScene(scene));

VBox vB=new VBox(30);
vB.getChildren().addAll(goBack,information);
vB.getStyleClass().add("vbox");

scene2=new Scene(vB,1600,900);
scene2.getStylesheets().add("CustomCSS.css");

//Criar Cena 3
Label Banda1=new Label("Earth, Wind & Fire");
Banda1.getStyleClass().add("Bandas");

Label Banda2=new Label("Louis Armstrong and His Hot Five");
Banda2.getStyleClass().add("Bandas");

Label Banda3=new Label("Bob James");
Banda3.getStyleClass().add("Bandas");

Label Banda4=new Label("Larry Carlton");
Banda4.getStyleClass().add("Bandas");

Label promo= new Label("AS MELHORES BANDAS DE JAZZ DE TODOS OS TEMPOS!\nNÃO PERCAS A OPORTUNIDADE DE ARRANJAR JÁ OS BILHETES.\nBilhetes disponíveis através de:\nCOMBO TICKET C/ CP.\nONLINE NO SITE DO EVENTO.\nNA SUA AGÊNCIA MAIS PROXIMA.");
promo.getStyleClass().add("promo");
VBox cartazBox= new VBox(40);
cartazBox.getChildren().addAll(goBack,Banda1,Banda2,Banda3,Banda4,promo);
cartazBox.getStyleClass().add("vbox");
scene3=new Scene(cartazBox,1600,900);
scene3.getStylesheets().add("CustomCSS.css");
window.setScene(scene);
window.show();
```

Comment: A node can only be used in a single place in a single scene.

Comment: A node can only appear once in one scene graph (for example, what would you expect `goBack.getParent()` or `goBack.getLayoutX()` to give in your example?). When you add a node to a parent, if it is already contained in another parent, it is silently removed from the previous parent.